# GDlib Alphablending Overlay

Tags: php, imagemagick, gdlib

Im looking for a Solution to alphablend 2 JPG images with PHP. Both Images should have 50% Transparency in the end so you can see both images at once in the final image.

I just cant find a soltuion for it in Stackoverflow or on php.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it via ImageMagick.